# Deriving a restricted efficient GMM estimator with common coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-moments

I'm having a bit of trouble in doing exercise 3.
For us to compare with Pooled OLS, and Random effects model, it seems that we must assume that we're under conditional homoskedasticity, and the set of instruments is the same across equations.

I don't quite understand how are we to estimate the coefficients vector, exploiting those moment conditions? Do we incorporate those regressors in the instruments? If so, wouldn't that allow the set of instruments to vary across the equations?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient GMM is given in (4.6.6). The IVs are $x_{im} = z_{im}$ here and the weighting matrix is $\hat W_{mh}$ the $(m,h)$ block of $\hat S$ given in (4.3.2) with $x_{im} = z_{im}$. It is different from POLS unless the estimated error covariance is spherical. It's not RE because the orthogonality conditions used here are different.